# Set Win-Bash Prompt to Current Directory?

Tags: bash

How can I make the [Win-Bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net) prompt always print the current folder?

I want it to display something like:

```
MyPC /Data/MyFiles # _
```

(assuming I'm in the folder `/Data/MyFiles`)
whereas right now, it always displays

```
bash$ _
```

no matter what folder I'm in.

Comment: Not knowing about Win Bash specifically, but assuming that they are largely similar - Can you elaborate?  whats does **echo "${PS1}"** show?  And do you have any bashrc file (and evidence that it actually runs) ... thanks

Comment: @nhed: I monitored Win-Bash and found out that it tries to access `C:\.bashrc`, so that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set your prompt like this:

```
PS1="\w\$ "
```

and put that in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Win-Bash apparently uses a *very* old version of Bash, so it's going to be somewhat limited.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was forced to put this in `C:\.bashrc` (that's the only directory it looked in), so I did that and it worked! :)